# Postfix: Custom Reject Message for Certain Email Adresses

Tags: postfix, email-bounces

I would like to reject mails to a certain address with a custom message.  Mails to other non existing addresses should be unchanged. How can I do that? I'm using Postfix 2.7.0 on Ubuntu 10.4.

Background: My websites sends mails to my users, and so far, my personal address is used as the sender. I would like to change this to a noreply@... address, but since the users reply quite often to these emails, I would like to send them a helpful reject message.

Thanks!

Comment: So, basically you want to *reply* with a helpful reject message on messages sent to a *noreply* address :)

Comment: I recommend using a customer service email address if possible, rather than a noreply@ email address. That way the users _can_ reply _and_ get a response. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create a `custom_replies` map (i.e. `/etc/postfix/custom_replies`) with the following contents:

```
noreply@mydomain.com REJECT Like I said, NOREPLY
```

Run `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/custom_replies`.

Edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and put the following as the first check of the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`:

```
check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/custom_replies,
```

Then issue a `sudo postfix reload`.

Try sending email to `noreply@mydomain.com`:

```
$ telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
HELO localhost
250 mydomain.com
MAIL FROM: <god@mydomain.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: <noreply@mydomain.com>
554 5.7.1 <noreply@mydomain.com>: Recipient address rejected: Like I said, NOREPLY
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

Comment: Obviously I ran the telnet session on the mail server itself.

Comment: I recommend using PCRE (and not HASH) so you do need to run "postmap" every time the file is modified. It's just one less hassle.