# Postfix bounces on user unknown alias (`"|exit 67"`) instead of rejecting mail

Tags: postfix, email-bounces, aliases

I have a small postfix server for a few domains of my own (matched with mydestination = pcre:/etc/postfix/mydestinations).
I set some non-virtual aliases

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
```

In this file I defined generic aliases

```
generic: someuser
```

And with a `recipient_delimiter = -` I can now use `generic-something@example.com` as a disposable email address. As some of these generic addresses get spammed I can discard all email [according to alias](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html):

```
generic-spammed: /dev/null
```

This works beautifully, but it means I keep accepting those emails. Instead I would like to reject them. [Reading the aliases doc, it seems I should be able to do the following to reject email with "user unknown" errors](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html):

```
generic-spammed:    |"exit 67"
```

Unfortunately the emails are bounced instead of rejected, contributing to backscatter. This means they are initially accepted, with `250 OK` returned to the sender, before being bounced.

This is similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/792442/postfix-reject-not-bounce-unknown-virtual-aliases), except I am using local destinations, not virtual ones. I have `smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient` on as the default, and I suspect my problem is due to [the following sentence from the doc](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient):

```
The recipient domain matches $mydestination, $inet_interfaces or $proxy_interfaces, but the recipient is not listed in $local_recipient_maps, and $local_recipient_maps is not null.
```

Is the problem that the recipient is listed at all? Is there a way to reject these emails instead of bouncing them?

`postconf -n` returns the following:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mua_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
mua_helo_restrictions = permit
mua_sender_restrictions = permit
mydestination = pcre:/etc/postfix/mydestinations
mydomain = xavasite.net
myhostname = dent.xavasite.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 185.26.124.183 [2001:4b98:dc2:47:216:3eff:fe3f:43d3]
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = local:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
policy-spf_time_limit = 3600s
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = -
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_junk_command_limit = 1
smtpd_milters = local:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, reject_rbl_client psbl.surriel.com, reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/2015/GandiStandardSSLCA2.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/2015/xavier.robin.name.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/2015/xavier.robin.name.key
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = RC4
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to reject those emails using the [`check_recipient_access`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_recipient_access) configuration. It allows creating a hash db file containing REJECT statements for specific email addresses.

I created a file named `/etc/postfix/alias_disable` with the following content:

```
generic-spammed@example.com     REJECT
```

Then I ran `postmap alias_disable` and added a line in `main.cf` within the scope of `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        [...]
       **check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/alias_disable**
```

Now the emails are rejected, without a bounce:

```
554 5.7.1 <generic-spammed@example.com>: Recipient address rejected: Access denied;
```

Apparently it should be possible to [customize the reject message](https://serverfault.com/questions/267446/postfix-custom-reject-message-for-certain-email-adresses), including with [several postfix actions](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) but I haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the quote incorrectly on the aliases file

```
generic-spammed:    |"exit 67"
```

it should be

```
generic-spammed:    "|exit 67"
```

Also, by default postfix will disallow delivery to "|command" so you also need to include the following

```
allow_mail_to_commands = alias,forward,include
```

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#allow_mail_to_commands

Comment: Interesting, both versions can be found on the internet, and they both seem to work and give the same result on my server at least. I happened to have allow_mail_to_commands = alias,forward so that isn't it either. But thanks for trying.